# How would I go about saving and reading an integer then a struct array in the same .dat file?

Tags: c

Basicly, I have a counter that I need to save and read as an integer as the first thing in a data file while in the same data file save a struct array. I don't want to post my entire code as its a bit too long but below are the functions that I have written so far.

```
void write(InventoryItemType *writefile[], int count)
{
    int i;
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr=fopen("inventory.dat","wb");
    if(ptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to Open File\n");
        system("pause");
        return;
    }
    putw(count, ptr);
    for(i=0;i < count; i++)
    {
        fwrite(&writefile[i], sizeof writefile, 1, ptr);
    }
    fclose(ptr);
}
InventoryItemType *read(InventoryItemType *readfile[])
{
    int i, count;
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr=fopen("inventory.dat","wb");
    if(!ptr)
    {
        printf("Unable to Open File\n");
        system("pause");
        return;
    }
    count=getcount();
    for(i=0;i < count; i++)
    {
        fread(&readfile[i], sizeof readfile, 1, ptr);
    }
    fclose(ptr);
    return *readfile;
}
int getcount(void)
{
    int i;
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr=fopen("inventory.dat","wb");
    if(ptr<=0)
    {
        i=0;
        return i;
    }
    i=getw(ptr);
    fclose(ptr);
    return i;
}
```

I call the functions in the main block like so:

At the top of code for file reading:

```
int i=0, item_count=getcount();
char selection, code[4];
InventoryItemType *inventoryItems[MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE];
*inventoryItems=read(inventoryItems);
```

And at the exit statements like so:

```
write(inventoryItems, item_count);
break;
```

I am relatively new to this concept so any help would be appreciated.

memmory allocation edit:

```
InventoryItemType *addItem(void)
{
    InventoryItemType *current = (InventoryItemType*) malloc (sizeof *current);
    system("cls");
    if(current == NULL)
        return NULL;
    ....
    system("cls");
    return current;
}
```

EDIT #2: I tried my best to implement your suggestions. Currently, I get a value of -1 for count. Here is the updated code:

Calling Functions for Reading:

```
int i=0, item_count=getcount();
char selection, code[4];
InventoryItemType *inventoryItems[MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE];
reader(inventoryItems);

Calling Function for writing:

case 'A' :
    writer(inventoryItems, item_count);
    break;
```

Reading Functions:

```
void reader(InventoryItemType *readfile[])
{
    int i, count;
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr=fopen("inventory.dat","rb");
    if(!ptr)
    {
        printf("Unable to Open File\n");
        system("pause");
        return;
    }
    count=getcount();
    for(i=0;i < count; i++)
    {
        fread(&readfile[i], sizeof (InventoryItemType), 1, ptr);
    }
    fclose(ptr);
    return; 
}
int getcount(void)
{
    int i;
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr=fopen("inventory.dat","rb");
    if(ptr==NULL)
    {
        i=0;
        return i;
    }
    i=getw(ptr);
    return i;
}
```

Writing Functions:

```
void writer(InventoryItemType *writefile[], int count)
{
    int i;
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr=fopen("inventory.dat","wb");
    if(ptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to Open File\n");
        system("pause");
        return;
    }
    putw(count, ptr);
    for(i=0;i < count; i++)
    {
        fwrite(&writefile[i], sizeof (InventoryItemType), 1, ptr);
    }
}
```

EDIT #3: Entire code just.. frustration setting in Q_Q

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE 100

typedef struct {
    char item_Number[4];
    char item_Name[20];
    float item_Profit;
    float latest_Price;
    float selling_Price;
    unsigned int stock;
    unsigned int total_Sold;
}InventoryItemType;

void MainMenu();
void displayInventory(InventoryItemType *[], int);
void displaySales(InventoryItemType *[], int);
InventoryItemType *addItem(void);
InventoryItemType *deleteItem(InventoryItemType *[], int);
InventoryItemType *newShipment(InventoryItemType *[], int);
InventoryItemType *updateSales(InventoryItemType *[], int);
InventoryItemType *bubbleSort(InventoryItemType *[], int, char);
void swap(InventoryItemType *[], InventoryItemType *[]);
void writer(const char *,InventoryItemType *[], size_t );
void reader(const char *,InventoryItemType *[], size_t );

int main()
{
    int i=0, item_count=0;
    char selection, code[4];
    const char file[]={"inventory.dat"};
    InventoryItemType *inventoryItems[MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE];
    reader(file,inventoryItems,item_count);
    while(1)
    {
        MainMenu();

        scanf(" %c", &selection);
        switch(selection) 
        {
        case 'A' :
            displayInventory(inventoryItems, item_count);
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            continue;
        case 'B' :
            displaySales(inventoryItems, item_count);
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            continue;
        case 'C' :
            if(item_count == MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE - 1)
            {
                printf("Array is full\n");
                system("pause");
                continue;
            }
            inventoryItems[item_count] = addItem();
            item_count++;
            continue;
        case 'D' :
            *inventoryItems=deleteItem(inventoryItems, item_count);
            item_count--;
            continue;
        case 'E' :
            *inventoryItems=newShipment(inventoryItems, item_count);
            continue;
        case 'F' :
            *inventoryItems=updateSales(inventoryItems, item_count);
            continue;
        case 'G' :
            while(1)
            {
                system("cls");
                printf("A. Sort by Name\n");
                printf("B. Sort by Item Number\n");
                scanf(" %c", &selection);
                switch(selection)
                {
                case 'A' :
                    *inventoryItems=bubbleSort(inventoryItems, item_count, selection);
                    break;
                case 'B' :
                    *inventoryItems=bubbleSort(inventoryItems, item_count, selection);
                    break;
                default:
                    {
                        printf("Invalid Input!\n");
                        system("pause");
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            continue;
        case 'H' :
            while(1)
            {
                printf("Would you like to save your changed?\n");
                printf("A. Yes\n");
                printf("B. No\n");
                scanf(" %C", &selection);
                switch(selection)
                {
                case 'A' :
                    writer(file,inventoryItems,item_count);
                    break;
                case 'B' :

                    break;
                default:
                    {
                        printf("Invalid Input!\n");
                        system("pause");
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            continue;
        default :
            printf("Invalid Entry\n" );
            system("pause");
        }
    }
}
void MainMenu()
{
    system("cls");
    printf("A. Display Inventory\n");
    printf("B. Display Sales\n");
    printf("C. Add Item\n");
    printf("D. Remove Item\n");
    printf("E. Enter Shipment\n");
    printf("F. Update Sales\n");
    printf("G. Sort\n");
    printf("H. Exit\n");
    printf("Make a selection\n");
}
void displayInventory(InventoryItemType *display[], int key)
{
    system("cls");
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<key; i++)
        {
            printf("Item No.:%s\n", display[i]->item_Number);
            printf("Item Name:%s\n", display[i]->item_Name);
            printf("Item Stock:%d\n",display[i]->stock);
            printf("Item Purchased Price:%.2f\n", display[i]->latest_Price);
            printf("Total Value of Items:%.2f\n", (display[i]->stock)*(display[i]->latest_Price));
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
void displaySales(InventoryItemType *display[], int key)
{
    int i;
    float total_profit=0;
    system("cls");
    for(i=0; i<key; i++)
    {
        printf("Item No.:%s\n", display[i]->item_Number);
        printf("Item Name:%s\n", display[i]->item_Name);
        printf("Number of Item Sold:%d\n", display[i]->total_Sold);
        printf("Item Selling Price:%.2f\n", display[i]->selling_Price);
        printf("Total Profit from Item:%.2f\n", (display[i]->selling_Price-display[i]->latest_Price)*display[i]->total_Sold);
        total_profit=total_profit+((display[i]->selling_Price-display[i]->latest_Price)*display[i]->total_Sold);
        if(i==key-1)
            printf("\nTotal Over-all Profit:%.2f", total_profit);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
InventoryItemType *addItem(void)
{
    InventoryItemType *current = (InventoryItemType*) malloc (sizeof *current);
    system("cls");
    if(current == NULL)
        return NULL;
    printf("\nEnter details of item \n\n");
    printf("Enter Item no: \n");
    scanf("%s", current->item_Number);
    printf("Enter Item Name: \n");
    scanf("%s", current->item_Name);
    printf("Enter Stock: \n");
    scanf("%d", &current->stock);
    printf("Enter Purchase Price: \n");
    scanf("%f", &current->latest_Price);
    current->selling_Price=(current->latest_Price)*1.5;
    current->total_Sold=0;
    system("cls");
    return current;
}
InventoryItemType *deleteItem (InventoryItemType *deleted[], int item_count)
{
    char code[4];
    int i;
    system("cls");
    displayInventory(deleted,item_count);
    printf("Enter Item Number to be Deleted\n");
    scanf("%3s", code);
    for(i=0;i<item_count;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(code,deleted[i]->item_Number)==0)
            break;
    }
    free(deleted[i]);
    for(;i<item_count; i++)
        deleted[i]=deleted[i+1];
    return *deleted;
}
InventoryItemType *newShipment (InventoryItemType *shipment[], int item_count)
{
    char code[4];
    int i, add;
    float newprice;
    while(1)
    {
        system("cls");
        displayInventory(shipment, item_count);
        printf("\nEnter Item Number to Update Stock\n");
        scanf("%3s", code);
        for(i=0;i<item_count;i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(code,shipment[i]->item_Number)==0)
            {
                printf("Enter the Quantity of Item being added\n");
                scanf("%d", &add);
                printf("Enter the Purchase Price of the Item\n");
                scanf("%f", &newprice);
                shipment[i]->stock=shipment[i]->stock+add;
                shipment[i]->latest_Price=newprice;
                shipment[i]->selling_Price=shipment[i]->latest_Price*1.5;
                displayInventory(shipment, item_count);
                return *shipment;   
            }
        }
        printf("Invalid Item Number, Please Try Again\n");
        system("Pause");
        continue;
    }
}
InventoryItemType *updateSales (InventoryItemType *sale[], int item_count)
{
    char code[4], choice;
    int i, sold;
    while(1)
    {
        system("cls");
        displayInventory(sale, item_count);
        printf("\nEnter Item Number to Update Stock and Profits\n");
        scanf("%3s", code);
        for(i=0;i<item_count;i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(code,sale[i]->item_Number)==0)
            {
                printf("Enter the Quantity of Item Sold\n");
                scanf("%d", &sold);
                if(sale[i]->stock>sold)
                {
                    sale[i]->stock=sale[i]->stock-sold;
                    sale[i]->item_Profit=sale[i]->selling_Price*sold;
                    displayInventory(sale, item_count);
                    system("pause");
                    return *sale;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Invalid Input!\nThere can not be more sold than in stock!\nWould you like to try again?\n");
                    printf("A. Yes\n");
                    printf("B. No\n");
                    scanf(" %c", &choice);
                    switch(choice)
                    {
                    case 'A' :
                        system("cls");
                        displayInventory(sale, item_count);
                        continue;
                    case 'B' :
                        return *sale;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Invalid Item Number, Please Try Again\n");
                system("Pause");
            }
        }
    }
}
void swap(InventoryItemType *a[], InventoryItemType *b[])
{
    InventoryItemType *temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}
InventoryItemType *bubbleSort(InventoryItemType *sorting[], int item_count, char swaptype)
{
    int i, sorted;
    system("cls");
    if(swaptype=='A')
    {
        do{
            sorted=1;
            for (i = 0; i < item_count - 1; i++) 
            {
                if (strcmp(sorting[i]->item_Name,sorting[i + 1]->item_Name)==1) 
                {
                    swap(&sorting[i],&sorting[i + 1]);
                    sorted = 0;
                }
            }
        }while(!sorted);
    }
    else
    {
        do{
            sorted=1;
            for (i = 0; i < item_count - 1; i++) 
            {
                if (strcmp(sorting[i]->item_Number,sorting[i + 1]->item_Number)==1) 
                {
                    swap(&sorting[i],&sorting[i + 1]);
                    sorted = 0;
                }
            }
        }while(!sorted);
    }
    printf("Your Inventory is Sorted!\n\n");
    system("pause");
    return *sorting;
}
void writer(const char *fname,const InventoryItemType *saveinventory , size_t count)
{
    FILE *ptr = fopen(fname, "wb");
    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        fclose(ptr);
        printf("Unable to Open File\n");
        system("pause");
        return;
    }
    if (fwrite(&count, sizeof(count), 1, ptr)!= 1) 
    {
        fclose(ptr);
        printf("Write count failed\n");
        system("pause");
        return;
    }
    if (fwrite(saveinventory, sizeof (*saveinventory), count, ptr)!= count)
    {
        fclose(ptr);
        printf("Write inventory failed\n");
        system("pause");
    }
}
void reader(const char *fname,InventoryItemType **inventory_ptr, size_t *count_ptr)
{
    InventoryItemType *inventory;
    size_t count;   
    FILE *ptr = fopen(fname, "rb");
    if(ptr == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to Open File\n");
        system("pause");
        return;
    }

    if (fread(&count, sizeof count, 1, ptr)!= 1) {
        fclose(ptr);
        printf("Read count failed\n");
        system("pause");
        return;
    }

    inventory = (InventoryItemType *)malloc(sizeof *inventory * count);
    if (inventory == NULL && count > 0) {
        fclose(ptr);
        printf("Allocation failed\n");
        system("pause");
        return;
    }

    if (fread(inventory, sizeof *inventory, count, ptr)!= count) {
        fclose(ptr);
        free(inventory);
        printf("Read inventory failed\n");
        system("pause");
        return;
    }

    fclose(ptr);
    *inventory_ptr = inventory;
    *count_ptr = count;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Note that `sizeof writefile` in function `write` will be the size of a _pointer_, not the size of an element. Use `sizeof InventoryItemType`. Same in `read`.

Comment: I did have that before as some of the research I did also had similar structures, but then I get the error `error C2198: 'fread' : too few arguments for call` for both functions.  How would I work around this?

Comment: As I suggested: `fwrite(&writefile[i], sizeof InventoryItemType, 1, ptr);`

Comment: `int getcount(void) [ ....  ptr=fopen("inventory.dat","wb");` is questionable    as the calling code has the file opened in _write_ mode too.

Comment: Updated `reader()` function will not work as needed as it reads the first `readfile[i]` from the beginning of the file, same place as `count`.  Try `count=getcount();` --> `count = getw(ptr);`

Comment: Curious: why code  the cast `(InventoryItemType *)` in `inventory = (InventoryItemType *)malloc(sizeof *inventory * count);`?

Comment: Declaration is `void reader(const char *,InventoryItemType *[], size_t );`, yet definition differs with  `void reader(const char *fname,InventoryItemType **inventory_ptr, size_t *count_ptr)`  Save time:  1) use the same signature for both, 2) do not use a C++ compiler for C code.  3) Enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: I use visual studio to write the code. It has something to do with the way the compiler works. It is required but functions the same as `inventory = malloc(sizeof *inventory * count);`

Comment: C code does not require the cast.  Using a C++ compiler to compile C code leads to trouble - like not complaining about the mismatched definition/declaration.  Configure VS to compile as C code, not C++.

Comment: Okay, now compiling strictly in C. I did not receive any mismatch errors but I am assuming that is a VS issue (not the best c compiler). I adjusted the declaration to this `void reader(const char *,InventoryItemType *[], size_t *);` while the definition is `void reader(const char *fname,InventoryItemType *inventory_ptr[], size_t *count_ptr)` I could not just pass the item_count to the function so I adjusted the top of the code to this 
`size_t item_count=0;
 size_t *ptr;
 reader(file,inventoryItems, ptr=&item_count);`

Comment: @Trial'n'Error " I could not just pass the `item_count` to the function" --> That is good.  `reader()` does need to be given a _count_.  Instead `reader()` expects an _address_ to the count.  `ptr` not needed.  Try `InventoryItemType *inventoryItems; size_t item_count=0; size_t *ptr; reader(file,&inventoryItems, &item_count);`

Comment: @Trial'n'Error Note: `void writer(const char *,InventoryItemType *[], size_t );` does not match `void writer(const char *fname,const InventoryItemType *saveinventory , size_t count)`.  "I did not receive any mismatch errors " may be because the compilers warnings are not fully enabled.

Comment: @chux `inventoryItems' is already pointer, isn't `&inventoryItems` incorrect? I get an incompatibility error when using it. Without it I can pass `&item_count` but hit the same problem of not reading count properly. Could it be an error with wrote function?

Comment: @chux Adjusted to: `void writer(const char *fname,const InventoryItemType *saveinventory, size_t count)` To call the function I used: `writer(file,*inventoryItems,item_count);` on a side note: does the fact that this is a struct array change how I should pass to functions? Originally (with my limited knowledge), I thought I would need a loop to call each element of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I go about saving and reading an integer then a struct array in the same .dat file?

I  suggest an architecture change.  Rather than

```
// void write(InventoryItemType *writefile[], int count)
// InventoryItemType *read(InventoryItemType *readfile[])
```

Consider

```
// return 0 on success
int iwrite(const char *fname, const InventoryItemType *inventory, size_t count)
int iread(const char *fname, InventoryItemType **inventory, size_t *count)
```

---

I found OP's approach too tangled.

To write, open the file, write the count and data.  Recall the inventory is still allocated and eventually needs to be freed.

```
int iwrite(const char *fname, const InventoryItemType *inventory, size_t count) {
  FILE *ptr = fopen(fname, "wb");
  if(ptr == NULL) {
    // printf("Unable to Open File\n");
    return 1;
  }

  if (fwrite(&count, sizeof count, 1, ptr)!= 1) {
    fclose(ptr);
    // printf("Write count failed\n");
    return 2;
  }

  if (fwrite(inventory, sizeof *inventory, count, ptr)!= count) {
    fclose(ptr);
    // printf("Write inventory failed\n");
    return 3;
  }

  fclose(ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

To write, open the file, read the count, allocate memory for the inventory and then read the inventory.

```
int iread(const char *fname, InventoryItemType **inventory_ptr, size_t *count_ptr) {
  FILE *ptr = fopen(fname, "rb"); // read mode
  if(ptr == NULL) {
    // printf("Unable to Open File\n");
    return 1;
  }

  size_t count;
  if (fread(&count, sizeof count, 1, ptr)!= 1) {
    fclose(ptr);
    // printf("Read count failed\n");
    return 2;
  }

  InventoryItemType *inventory = malloc(sizeof *inventory * count);
  if (inventory == NULL && count > 0) {
    fclose(ptr);
    // printf("allocation failed\n");
    return 3;
  }

  if (fread(inventory, sizeof *inventory, count, ptr)!= count) {
    fclose(ptr);
    free(inventory);
    // printf("Read inventory failed\n");
    return 3;
  }

  fclose(ptr);
  *inventory_ptr = inventory;
  *count_ptr = count;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the "de-spaghetting" of my code. Currently I get errors during read, specifically at count. I created void functions with system pauses at different print statements. The declaration of the function looks like this: `void reader(const char *,const InventoryItemType *, size_t);`.

Comment: @Trial'n'Error Take care about _reading_ `count`.  It should be _written_ with   updated code too.

Comment: I am officially out of trial and error options without getting arbitrary. I updated my question with my entire code...could you please take a look ... this is much more frustrating than just `fscanf` and `fprintf`

Answer (score 0):

Thee are a number of problems in your code:

```
InventoryItemType *inventoryItems[MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE];
*inventoryItems=read(inventoryItems);
```

You declare an array of pointers to items and then you read the items. But in the code for reading the items, I do not see you allocate memory for the items. Then, when the function returns, you assign the returned result to `*inventoryItems`, that is you dereference the array and so have its first element. This seems like nonsense and you compiler should have complained. Do not return any thing from the function, except success/failure.

And note that `read` is the name of a function from the standard library. Use another name. Also for `write`.

When yu open the file, you specify `"wb"` but that means you open the file for *writing*. That should be `"rb"` (read binary).

In the `read` function, you read `sizeof readfile` bytes. But `readfile` is a pointer to an array of pointers. So `sizeof readfile` will be the size of a pointer. You should use `sizeof *readfile[i]` or `sizeof(InventoryItemType)`.

But before you read anything into `readfile[i]`, you should allocate memory for it! And note that `readfile[i]` is already a pointer, so you don't need the `&` operator in `fread` and `fwrite`.

As an example of what it should be, I provide the `read` function:

```
int myread(InventoryItemType *readfile)
{
    int i, count;
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr=fopen("inventory.dat","rb");   // "rb" = Read Binary
    if(!ptr)
    {
        printf("Unable to Open File\n");
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    count=getcount();
    for(i=0;i < count; i++)
    {
        readfile[i]= malloc(sizeof(InventoryItemType));
        fread(readfile[i], sizeof(InventoryItemType), 1, ptr);
    }
    fclose(ptr);
    return 1;
}
```

..and turn warnings of your compiler on!

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply. I do allocated memory in another function which loooks like what I just added to the original code. Would that suffice?

Comment: Hmmm. `readfile[i] - malloc(...)` is  a pointer to data.  Does not `fread( ...` need `fread(readfile[i],.. `?   (no `&`)

Comment: @Chux, thanks for noticing. Fixed.

Comment: Almost right: suggest `fread(readfile[i], sizeof readfile[i][0], 1, ptr);`  (add dereference) (Sorry if my earlier comment lead you astray).  IAC: OP's use of `int myread(InventoryItemType *readfile[])` looks like it should have been `int myread(InventoryItemType *readfile)` with memory allocated in the calling code.

Comment: @Chux, I was sloppy. There were so many errors... For simplicity I now prefer `sizeof(InventoryItemType)`.

Comment: I implemented that and it compiled, thanks! I updated the  code with as many of the alterations as I could